# Unable to upgrade RAM on an old 32-bit IBM ThinkPad-T60 running FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE

Tags: memory, thinkpad, freebsd

I found an old IBM ThinkPad-T60 and I've been restoring it to get it ready to use. The machine came with 1 x 1GB of 333Mhz PC2 SODIMM RAM. Surprisingly, it has a 32-bit processor (my ThinkPad-T60p has a 64-bit processor), so OS options were more limited.

I was able to install FreeBSD 13.0 GENERIC on it, and it works fine. But I wanted to upgrade the RAM, and got two 2GB 667Hhz PC2 SODIMM RAM, which the ThinkPad forums says will work with the ThinkPad-T60 (and indeed the purchase package lists the T60 as a machine with which the RAM is compatible). The ThinkPad forums warn that the motherboard maxes out at 3 GB, but that putting 4 GB of RAM in the machine will translate into 3 GB of usable RAM. I did the same thing with my ThinkPad-T60p running Bodhi Linux, and it worked.

When I install the new RAM, the IBM BIOS recognizes all 4 GB of RAM, but FreeBSD halts during boot, even before the FreeBSD startup splash screen. I have the drive encrypted, and the bootup sequence prompts for a password, and then halts during the step:

```
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
```

Because it's 32-bit, I haven't found a USB boot stick that will let me run another OS on it to diagnose if the boot stick OS recognizes the new RAM.

When I replace the old RAM chip, everything works again.

Please advise. I've found nothing in the FreeBSD forums about this.

Comment: Memtest recognizes 3 GB of RAM after using the new RAM in the laptop, and the laptop boots up with the new RAM when I use Slacko Puppy 32-bit USB boot device.

Comment: I am able to boot from the FreeBSD install USB drive with the new RAM installed. I would really like to get a working kernel on my original install.

Comment: Why not upgrade the processor to  64bit one?

Comment: @Moab - It’s a laptop processor that supports DDR2. The processor likely is worth more as scrap so putting any great deal of money into it seems wasteful

Answer (score 0):

"Long mode" means 64-bit.

You are trying to install a 64-bit release on a 32-bit computer.

You should choose in the
[Download FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/where/)
page the version for "i386".

Comment: Yeah, I realized my mistake and used a 32-bit install media. FreeBSD boots up on the 32-bit install USB drive, but not on the original install.